# Очень большие числа (30-ти значные)

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Программа пишется в MVS (c++). Что делать, если мне нужно оперировать c 30-значными (26^20) числами? Можно ли как-то, не сохраняя значение в переменной (нет таких больших типов) сразу конвертировать число в строку? И как затем, к примеру складывать и умножать такие числа (в строковом формате), не используя переменные?

Заранее спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: исключительно из любопытства - а зачем? Вы решили пересчитать атомы во Вселенной?

Comment: для некоторых математических задач таких размеров бывает мало. Например, поиск больших простых чисел или [чисел мерсенна](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начните, к примеру, с этого класса - [cpp-bigint](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/). Он очень маленький и простой (всего один h и cpp файл, который можно добавить в проект). Там же в архиве есть `main.cpp` есть пример использования.

Comment: Я не настолько знаю С++, как включить класс в проект, если в архиве только exe файл?

Comment: это разработчики шалят. Зайдите по ссылке, найдите там Files (чуть выше и левее от зеленой кнопки "скачать"). Перейдите по этой ссылке. Увидите "C++ BigInt Class", кликайте. Там увидите "Version 4.0" и другие версии. Кликайте по "Version 4.0". А там найдете архив с названием bigint-4-0-src.zip или bigint-4-0-src.7z.

Или попробуйте [эту ссылку](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/files/C%2B%2B%20BigInt%20Class/Version%204.0/bigint-4-0-src.zip/download). Но SourceForge он такой, может и не пустить напрямую.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017058/building-gmp-library-with-visual-studio